# AS3 Linking-Loading Another Swf File

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i made catching game and i have the swf file. In another flash project, i want to call that swf. I created a button and wrote the codes below.

```
btnn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_4);

import fl.display.ProLoader;
var fl_ProLoader_4:ProLoader;


var fl_ToLoad_4:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(fl_ToLoad_4)
    {
        fl_ProLoader_4 = new ProLoader();
        fl_ProLoader_4.load(new URLRequest("CathingGame.swf"));
        addChild(fl_ProLoader_4);
    }
    else
    {
        fl_ProLoader_4.unload();
        removeChild(fl_ProLoader_4);
        fl_ProLoader_4 = null;
    }

    fl_ToLoad_4 = !fl_ToLoad_4;
}
```

But when i click the button, i have the error below. What could be the possible solutions? I think i have this error because in the catching game, my fla and actionscript are in different file. I mean i use external .as file. Not in the fla file.

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at CatchingGame()

Comment: With `if(fl_ToLoad_4)` are you trying to check if its **null** or if it's **false**.  Your `Else` statement definately makes it null and by the time you try to do   `fl_ToLoad_4 = !fl_ToLoad_4;` its too late. Finally thjat `fl_ProLoader_4.load` needs an **eventListener** for when game load is complete (processed all bytes). in the **event complete** function is where you can then add to stage. Here you addChild something which may not even exist yet to Flash Player...

Comment: Thank you, i solved the problem by moving the codes inside the fla file. Then it worked like a charm. I didn't try to call the swf. I couldn't manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Your loading code is fine, but exception is originated from the `CatchingGame` code, so that's not possible to say for sure what's the reason.

But, if (as I guess) your game works fine when it's launched without preloading the most probable reason for `null object reference` in that case is too earlier accessing to `stage` property from the game. Try to move game initiation logic to `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event handler like in example below:

```
    public function MyGame()
    {
        if (stage)
        {
            init();
        }
        else
        {
            addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage );
        }
    }

    private function onAddedToStage( event:Event ):void
    {
        removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage );
        init();
    }

    private function init():void
    {
        //place init logic here
    }
```

If my guess wrong, add more code from `CatchingGame` swf.

Comment: Thank you, i solved the problem by moving the codes inside the fla file. Then it worked like a charm. I didn't try to call the swf. I couldn't manage it.